# ¿Fecha en cabecera HTTP Date incorrecta?

Tags: rest, cabeceras-http

Tras una petición HTTP a una api REST recibo la siguiente cabecera

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: RestDriver POST/1.0
Date: mer, 10 gen 2018 13:20:34  GMT
```

La hora de mi sistema, siendo "01:00 GMT", me indicaba 13:20:34

¿Es inválida la cabecera Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El header **NO** es incorrecto por dar la hora incorrecta, simplemente indica que el server no tiene bien configurada la fecha/hora. [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date) tiene que entregarte la hora del servidor, que no necesariamente va a ser aproximada a la tuya. La importancia de Date es principalmente para calcular otros valores entregados, por ejemplo en [Expires](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires), donde se indica la fecha y hora en la que debe caducar el contenido y/o el caché (y es en relación a la fecha/hora del servidor, no la del cliente).

Pero **SÍ** es incorrecto porque:

1. Está en italiano ([ICU Locale “italiano” (it)](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/it/index.html)), cuando debería estar en inglés <sup>[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date)</sup>.
2. Tiene 2 espacios entre la hora y `GMT`, cuando debería tener 1 solo.
3. El día de la semana y el mes deberían empezar con una mayúscula (aunque ya por estar en italiano está mal).

---

El encabezado Date está definido por el [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18),
que usa el formato definido en la [sección 3.3 (Date/Time Formats)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3) como aceptables:

> ```
> Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT  ; RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123
> Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT ; RFC 850, obsoleted by RFC 1036
> Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994       ; ANSI C's asctime() format
> ```

y establece que se **DEBEN** enviar únicamente en el primer formato:

> ```
>  rfc1123-date = wkday "," SP date1 SP time SP "GMT"
>  date1        = 2DIGIT SP month SP 4DIGIT
>                 ; day month year (e.g., 02 Jun 1982)
>  time         = 2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT
>                 ; 00:00:00 - 23:59:59
>  wkday        = "Mon" | "Tue" | "Wed"
>               | "Thu" | "Fri" | "Sat" | "Sun"
>  month        = "Jan" | "Feb" | "Mar" | "Apr"
>               | "May" | "Jun" | "Jul" | "Aug"
>               | "Sep" | "Oct" | "Nov" | "Dec"
> ```

- Se deben enviar en inglés.

**Ejemplo correcto:**

```
Date: Tue, 30 Jan 2017 15:10:20 GMT
```

---

[1]: [Headers - Date (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date)
[2]: [RFC 2616, sec 14.18 - Date (w3.org)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18)
[3]: [RFC 2616, sec 3.3 - Date/Time Formats (w3.org)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Mariano, muy amable. Ahora lo tengo claro